# Sum of cells in column - linked to content of second column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel spreadsheet with almost 10,000 rows.

There are two columns I want to work with to solve a specific problem. They look a little like this.

```
Column A    Column B

1           String A

2   

2           String B

1           String C

1   

1   

1           String D

5           String E
```

I want to be able to add all the numbers that appear in Column A from one string to the next, and I want to display that sum in a third column opposite the first string.

So the result for my excerpt would be

```
Column A    Column B    Column 3

1           String A            3

2   

2           String B            2

1           String C            3

1   

1   

1           String D            1

5           String E            1
```

The number of rows to add  and assign to each string is not consistent.

Can anyone advise me how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper column C
Fill C with the following:
in C1 write `=B1`
in C2 write:
`=IF(ISBLANK(B2),C1,B2)`
and drag it down
in D1 write:
`=IF(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,C1)=1,SUMPRODUCT(--(C1:C8=C1)*A1:A8),"")`
and drag it down
C1:C8 is the column of string
A1:A8 is the column of numbers to sum
When finish copy column D and `paste special values` in column E
Now you can delete columns C and D

Comment: Actually this doesn't work - it counts up to 7 rows, so it doesn't work if the string appears more often than that. I missed this in my initial test.    
If I change the values to C1:C100 everything will work but I wonder if this could be done with variables?

Comment: you have to change it according to your Data and make $C1:$C$100 and $A$1:$A$8 in the sumproduct but not in countif (keep it the same)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean after string E is at least 5?  How many rows are the max below any of the string?  If it is 2, here is something you might like to try.  Say string A is in cell B3, then in D3, the equation can be
=IF(NOT(B3=""),SUM(A3+(IF(B4="",A4,0))+IF(B5="",A4,0)))),"")  This is assuming there are max 2 blank rows below any string, this only works for 2 blank rows.  Then only the sum from the string row and the blank rows will show up.  Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In cell C1 - to identify the group heading as 0
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)), 0, A1)
In cell D1, define the heading value and sum of blank rows
=IF(C1=0, A1, IF(AND(NOT(C1=0),C2=0), A1,C1+D2))
In cell E1, only one value to each group
=IF(AND(C1=0, C2=0), D1, IF(AND(C1=0, NOT(C2=0)),D1+D2, ""))
Column E1 only shows the sum of the number to its own group.

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to help me out. I am afraid that this didn't work for me. I think my explanation wasn't very clear.